# Zend Framework: How to find a table row by the value of a specified column?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I am implementing my model exactly like the [quickstart guide](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart/create-a-model-and-database-table).

In my model I am trying to implement a `findByToken()` method. The current `find()` method accepts an `$id` parameter, but I want to find by the value of a different column.

```
//excerpt from the quickstart guide
public function find($id, Default_Model_Guestbook $guestbook)
{
    $result = $this->getDbTable()->find($id);
    if (0 == count($result)) {
        return;
    }
    $row = $result->current();
    $guestbook->setId($row->id)
              ->setEmail($row->email)
              ->setComment($row->comment)
              ->setCreated($row->created);
}
```

I tried doing something like this, but I don't think it worked:

```
$db = $this->getDbTable();
$where = $db->getAdapter()->quoteInto('token = ?', $token);
$result = $db->find($where);
```

What would be the proper way to find a row by the value of a specified column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$result = $db->fetchAll($where);
```

or if you are trying to retrieve only one row.

```
$result = $db->fetchRow($where);
```

You could also use the Zend_Db_Select Object, keeping the adapter a little further abstracted:

```
$db = $this->getDbTable();
$select = $db->select()->where('token = ?', $token);
$result = $db->fetchAll($select);
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be easily done by creating select object and fetching a row using this object. It's well described in manual: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.execute

Your code could look like:

```
$select = $this->getDbTable()->select()->where('token = ?', (string) $token);
$row = $this->getDbTable()->fetchRow($select);
```