# Zend Framework: Select with join and PDO name param binding

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo, zend-db-table

I am using Zend Framework and have been trying to do a joined query and also use named param binding.  Referencing from the two posts below.  When I just do the join everything works.  When I add the name binding then it gets this error:

> Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were
>   bound

[How to do a joined query in the ZF tables interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412799/how-to-do-a-joined-query-in-the-zf-tables-interface)

[Zend Framework: How to find a table row by the value of a specified column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911558/zend-framework-how-to-find-a-table-row-by-the-value-of-a-specified-column)

I have scaled it way down trying to remove any possible errors but it is still getting the error and no idea why.

```
$query = "country = :cc";  // changing :cc to 'US' everything works
$params = array(':cc' => 'US');

$db = $this->getDbTable();
$select = $db->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);

$select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
       ->join(array("daytable"), 'weektable.showid = daytable.id')
       ->where($query, $params);

$rowset = $db->fetchAll($select);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
->where('country = ?', 'US')
```

[Binding params with Zend_Db_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.where)

Comment: Yes this does work and I tried that but forgot to add it to my question. How come something like this doesn't ->where("day.dt BETWEEN ? AND ?", array($today, $tomorrow)); //'2011-09-25 02:00:00' AND '2011-09-26 18:00:00 but when I add the strings into the where it works just fine.

Comment: The other question is why does using the ':variable' method not work?

Comment: @Brandon http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2211 - Unresolved, they suggest pairing up where clauses. I don't know enough about the internals of Zend_Db_Select to give you an absolute answer but I have a hunch it's because Zend_Db doesn't always use a PDO adapter. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "country = ?";  // changing :cc to 'US' everything works
$param = 'US';

$db = $this->getDbTable();
$select = $db->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);

$select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
       ->join(array("daytable"), 'weektable.showid = daytable.id')
       ->where($query, $param);

$rowset = $db->fetchAll($select);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "country = :cc";  // changing :cc to 'US' everything works
$params = array('cc' => 'US');

$db = $this->getDbTable();
$select = $db->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);

$select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
       ->join(array("daytable"), 'weektable.showid = daytable.id')
       ->where($query);

$select->bind($params);

$rowset = $db->fetchAll($select);
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.